# @Asynchronous in a helper class? [SWF]

Tags: java, spring, amazon-swf

I have a workflow which is set up by spring with a scope of "workflow". The below code would show the message straight away instead of waiting 60 seconds. I think it's because of the way I'm constructing my Helper class... how do I fix Asynchronous methods to work within another class?

```
public class MyWorkflowImpl implements MyWorkflowImpl {
    private Helper helper = new Helper();
    @Override
    public do() {
        Promise<Void> timer = getTimer(60); //seconds
        helper.showMessage(timer);
    }
}

public class Helper {
    @Asynchronous
    public showMessage(Promise<Void> timer) {
        // show random message
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is correct. @Asynchronous should work on any method of any class having that AspectJ preprocessor is applied to all classes that use it.

Comment: I understand what you're saying about it being handled by an aspect, but for some reason it's just not deferring execution. Any ideas to troubleshoot?

Comment: Make sure that AspectJ is configured to process Helper class package. Check the AspectJ preprocessor logs for list of instrumented classes.

Comment: I set up a debugger and saw that the AsynchronousAspect is matching 2 out of 4 methods in the helper class. The signatures look similar.. trying to figure out why the other two aren't binding.

Comment: So the aspect requires the annotation and that the method be called. All 4 methods are public and are being called, but 2 of them are being called from within another @Asynchronous method. The 2 that aren't working are causing an IllegalStateException because the promise isn't ready. Still investigating..

Comment: It turns out that it was because my aop.xml didn't weave in the package my helper class was in. The aspect worked for two methods with Asynchronous because they were called from a class that was weaved in and the join was on the caller's side.

Comment: Good catch! IMHO it is something that should be fixed in the com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.aspectj.AsynchronousAspect class. Currently it weaves at the caller's side when specifying it on the target makes more sense.

Comment: I think I agree. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just for the record. AsynchronousAspectmakeAsynchronous should be annotated with       @Around("execution(@com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.annotations.Asynchronous * *(..)) && @annotation(asynchronousAnnotation)")